# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava'

Tags: android, kotlin

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/Users/liwei/Desktop/Schedule/app/src/main/java/com/schedule/MainActivity.kt
Error:(5, 16) Unresolved reference: os
Error:(12, 8) Unresolved reference: java
Error:(13, 8) Unresolved reference: java
Error:(21, 5) 'onCreate' overrides nothing
Error:(21, 47) Unresolved reference: Bundle
Error:(27, 26) Unresolved reference: SimpleDateFormat
Error:(28, 20) Unresolved reference: Date
Error:(28, 25) Unresolved reference: System
Error:(31, 19) Unresolved reference: Calendar
Error:(35, 41) Unresolved reference: Calendar
Error:(46, 47) Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but Context was expected
Error:(49, 25) Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but java.lang.String was expected
Error:(50, 24) The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Object
Error:(52, 45) Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but Context was expected
Error:(55, 25) Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but java.lang.String was expected
Error:(56, 24) The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Object
Error:(58, 45) Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but Context was expected
Error:(61, 25) Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but java.lang.String was expected
Error:(62, 24) The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Object
Error:(64, 44) Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but Context was expected
Error:(67, 25) Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but  java.lang.String was expected
Error:(68, 24) The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Object
Error:(70, 37) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val [ERROR : ].tab: PagerBottomTabLayout! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main
Error:(84, 5) Class 'OnTabItemlistener' must be declared abstract or implement abstract member public abstract fun onSelected(p0: Int, p1: Object!): Unit defined in me.majiajie.pagerbottomtabstrip.listener.OnTabItemSelectListener
Error:(85, 9) 'onSelected' overrides nothing
Error:(86, 19) Unresolved reference: UnsupportedOperationException
Error:(89, 9) 'onRepeatClick' overrides nothing
Error:(90, 19) Unresolved reference: UnsupportedOperationException
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava'.
```

> Compilation error. See log for more details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 8.812 secs
>   Information:29 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Kotlin Error
I don‘t down
Always appear this type of problem
Please
Help
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: this might be issue with data-binding library, remove all data-binding dependencies and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check if you have done all steps described in article below correctly: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

Then check which `kotlin-plugin` are you're already using. Hope you're not using `1.0.4` version and you chose `Stable` channel for `kotlin` updates, if not please downgrade it and rebuild projects.

There are some known issues dealing Kotlin with Data Binding library. Please, if possible - remove all its dependencies and rewrite binded code using `kotlin-extensions` library. Trust me, you don't need this library, when you're using code.

Then choose `File -> Invalidate Caches`, after invalidating and restart android studio, clean and rebuild your project.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

maybe u change version Kotlin language to ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.2-1'
by

[https://github.com/djuarez/KotlinCleanArchitecture/blob/master/build.gradle](https://github.com/djuarez/Kotlin-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/build.gradle)